# Find the Angle of a Rectangle's Diagonal

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, rectangles, angle

For a geometric rectangle with arbitrary sides of length $a$, $b$, and $c$.

The following are known:

1. $\theta$ where $\frac ac = \tan\theta$
2. $\phi$ where $\frac bc = \tan\phi$

Given only $theta$ and $phi$ find $x$ where $$\frac {\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}c = tan x$$

This can clearly be done with the equation: $$\arctan \sqrt{\tan^2\theta + \tan^2\phi}$$

I don't know a trigonometric identity to simplify this. But it seems like there should be one. Can anyone help me simplify this?

If it helps clarify here is a drawing of what I have tried to describe above:

[image]

Comment: It might be better if you can explain how a rectangle has three different side lengths $a, b, c$.  Can you put them on the diagram, for example?

Comment: WolframAlpha doesn't come up with anything quickly...

Comment: @BrianTung I've updated the image for what it's worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation containing $csc$  should not have it at all, else ok.

$ x = \arctan { \sqrt{ \tan ^2 \phi + \tan ^2 \theta .}} $

Comment: Ugh, well said, I intended to put $\arctan$ not $\csc$. Editing now.